# What does the word "environment" mean?

Tags: ide, environment

if someone asks me what kind of environment I developed in, does that mean what kind of IDE I used? Like Eclipse, Xcode, etc..?

sorry, i'm new to this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the ide as well as what kind of OS you are using such as windows or linux.